# May too much batch normalization hurt learning?

Tags: machine-learning, batch-normalization

I was experimenting with some CNN models and reading research material when I realized that it could happen that using only a single batch normalization layer at the early stages of the network could be beneficial compared to using a batch normalization layer after each convolutional layer (in case of CNNs).

The inspiration came from the paper *Comparison of feature learning methods for human activity recognition using wearable sensors* by F. Li, K. Shirahama, M. A. Nisar, L. Koping, and M. Grzegorzek.

I was wondering when and why does batch normalization hurt learning? Why using a single batch normalization instead of many may result in better learning?

Thanks